# Is error code P1684 common when the battery is replaced?

Tags: electrical, dodge, stratus

I have 2002 Dodge Stratus and I replaced battery yesterday as my old one died. Sometime this afternoon I noticed that the check engine light was on. After "key dance" method, I got P1684 error code. On quick search, the reason for P1684 was as follows:

***P1684 indicates there has been a power outage from your battery in the past 50 starts***

If this error code is correct, the then interval between the battery replacement must have reset the PCM model. However, the discussion forums have no mention of battery replacement as a probable cause, so my specific questions on this issues are:

- Could the battery replacement be the only reason for P1684?
- Will the engine check light automatically go out if everything is all right?
- Is there a way I could reset the engine check light myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your questions:

> Could the battery replacement be the only reason for P1684?

Assuming you mean the sole reason, as in cause the code by itself, yes it could. Anything that results in power loss to one of the controllers could set the code, disconnecting the battery is one possibility, but there are others such as a blown fuse of a failing connector.

> Will the engine check light automatically go out if everything is all right?

Yes, after 50 starts.

> Is there a way I could reset the engine check light myself?

Yes, you could go to an auto parts store that will loan you a ODB-II scan tool and use it to reset the check engine light.

Comment: i'll just add on chryslers when you replace the battery you should reset the learned adaptives. i don't know if theres a way to do this without a scantool.

Comment: As you suggested, I restarted the car for a few times and the check engine light went finally.

Answer (score 0):

Unhook your battery for about 20 min than, the codes memory will be gone unless it finds another code immediately. That works for my 02 Dodge  Grand caravan for the same code, which unhooking the battery Durning maitnence might of been the cause of p1684. In the first place. After it realized that the power was cut. Still no code it did come back once but just unhooked battery and is gone again.